# Concrete Steps Moving Away From House

Tags: concrete, stairs

I recently noticed that the steps on my front door appear to be moving away from my house.

The gap is large enough that some small critters appear to be getting in the gap to setup a nice home for themselves.

The question I have is, what should I do? Should I just fill in the gap? Is this something that requires professional attention?

Answer (score 1):

Where you live there are many basements, if you have one it is probably normal settling , in a newer home , what do you refer to as small critters? Many times foundations are back filled with rock that can settle and cause the separation for 20+ years , if this is the case and the gap is less than 3/4 inch I would use a latex caulk to seal it if larger I would contact professionals as suggested above